# Intersection of arrays algorithm

Tags: algorithm

I am reading the book *A Common-Sense Guide to Data Structures and Algorithms* and in Chapter 6/section "A Practical Example" there is the below intersection algorithm.

```
    ​function​ intersection(firstArray, secondArray){
​       ​let​ result = [];
​   
​       ​for​ (​let​ i = 0; i < firstArray.length; i++) {
​           ​for​ (​let​ j = 0; j < secondArray.length; j++) {
​               ​if​ (firstArray[i] == secondArray[j]) {
​                   result.push(firstArray[i]);
​                   ​break​;
​               }
​           }
​       }
​       ​return​ result;
​   }
```

It states that in the best case scenario (identical arrays) that there is only N comparisons `firstArray[i] == secondArray[j]` since there is a break statement. Without the break statement it would be N^2.

But I am finding that even with the break statement and identical arrays there still must be more than N comparisons as the inner loop iterates increasingly more as i gets bigger. But since this is a popular book I am thinking that I must be wrong and I am posting here for validation of that and an explanation why I am wrong.

Comment: Does it really say "identical arrays"? What *exactly* does it say?

Comment: In regard to adding the break statement - "But now, in the best-case scenario, where the two arrays are identical, we only have to perform N comparisons."

Comment: @Matt; No for `i!=j` this `firstArray[i] == secondArray[j]` if there are no duplicates in each array.

Comment: Look for me like N²/2 comparisons if there are  no duplicates in each array. (and the arrays are identical). A simple test run that counts the comparisons can answer the question.

Answer (score 5):

Best case indeed takes only N comparisons. But that's for cases like first array [3,3,3,3,3,3,3] and second array [3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. Identical *elements* in the first array and that value also appearing as the first element in the second array.

Looks like the book intended the arrays to represent sets, though, and not contain duplicates in either one. So it's an error in the book. Identical arrays without duplicates takes ~N²/2 comparisons. You can also find this already reported twice in [the book's errata](https://forum.devtalk.com/search?expanded=true&q=intersection%20best%20case) (the first place to look if you think you found an error in a book).

Comment: Thanks for the link to the errata, makes sense

Answer (score 2):

If you count the number of comparisons, you will see, that for arrays of length 5, you get 15 comparisons. We get 15 as 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5. The same thing will happen for longer arrays. In general the number of comparisons is

```
1 + 2 + ... + n = n * (n+1) / 2 = (n^2 + n) / 2 = O(n^2)
```

This means you are correct, this algorithm is still O(n^2). The only difference is, that it makes around half of the comparisons of the original version, but the time complexity does not change.

I also checked the book. The book never says that time complexity is different. It only says that the number of comparisons is n, which is still incorrect.

Comment: ok, so I wasn't going crazy

Answer (score -1):

Let's consider the following 2 **identical arrays**

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
array1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

In total, there'll be `6` comparisons made for the given example.
So the time complexity will be `O(N + N)` which is equal to `O(N)`.

So it seems the writer is correct about the best-case scenario (**identical arrays**) that there is only `N` comparisons.